# Getting large braces in MathJax

Tags: formatting, braces

In answering [this question on math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816540/proof-of-conways-simplicity-rule-for-surreal-numbers/1590205#1590205) I used the expression `{{{|}|}|}` and wanted to enlarge the outer braces to show the pairing.  I tried `\left \{ \left \{ \{ | \} \right \} \right \}`  (with backslashes on the braces that don't appear here) but the outer ones did not enlarge.  I found that `\Bigl \{\bigl\{\{ | \}|\bigr \}|\Bigr\}` worked.  Generally I like \left and \right as it stays nice if  change the contents.  Why doesn't it enlarge the outer braces here?

Comment: Sadly MathJax is off-topic here, but, uh, I can't reproduce this problem. Oh! I see now what your problem is! Er, yeah, the answer given below is exactly correct, it has nothing to do with `\left` and `\right` not working in MathJax, it's just that your content isn't big enough to cause further scaling. If you stick, say, a displaystyle fraction in there, you'll see that they scale as expected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pair `\left` `\right` takes parentheses big enough to enclose a box inside. Here the boxes are of the same height, so braces are the same.

However your version on math.stackexchange works very well. `\Bigl`, `\Bigr` and so on are sometimes the only acceptable solution, as in this case.

If you really need enlarging braces, you can change `\delimiterfactor` to a value greater than 1000, as in the following example (LaTeX, not working in MathJax, at least the version on math.se):

```
\documentclass{article}
 \begin{document}

$\left \{ \left \{ \{ | \} \right \} \right \}$

\delimiterfactor1100
$\left \{ \left \{ \{ | \} \right \} \right \}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\Big(` works, weirdly, even though `\Left(` breaks entirely.